# ajax post call returning undefined success message

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am posting some data to a PHP file which I would then like to send to a DB.
It seems my AJAX call is functioning nicely because I get an `alert` if the AJAX call was executed. However it seems that my data isn't being transported correctly. I get an `undefined` success message. I tried setting `async: true` but that didn't work. Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "sc_update_user.php",
    data: { 
        role_Id: 'my Id', 
        user_Id: 'user Id'    
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert('my message: ' + data.msg);
    }
});
```

```php
<?php include_once 'includes/sessions.php';
    include_once 'includes/connect.php';

    $roleId = $_POST['role_Id'];
    $userId = $_POST['user_Id'];

    // code to insert nto db //

    echo json_encode(array('msg'=>'the message'));
?>
```

The PHP is just a mockup to test, but it should work though right?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Have you checked the request in the console to see exactly what format the data is being returned in?

Comment: alert('my message: ' + data); write only this

Comment: @ParthTrivedi why should the string values being sent in the request be changed?

Comment: Do alert(JSON,stringify(data));  and tell us what are you getting in data.

Comment: alert(JSON,stringify(data)); results in data not showing at all.
so maybe sth wrong with he way that data is being sent back?

Comment: using alert(JSON,stringify(data)); doesn't alert anything :/

Comment: Add "dataType" parameter as "json" in your ajax call. If you do not have headers in your php you will receive an string. But first, try to make an alert with the data only and test if it is the desired result, maybe you received a non json string.

Comment: @elchininet 
I added 
     dataType: 'json',
to the ajax call but now i don't get an alert at all .....

Comment: Look at my comment. First try to alert only the data and check if it is the desired result. Then do the rest. Maybe your data contains another string with a Warning or an Error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your code to following.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "sc_update_user.php",
    data: { 
        role_Id: 'my Id', 
        user_Id: 'user Id'    
    },
    success: function(data){
        output = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(output.msg); //Check console for output
    }
});
```

Parse the response and access the object.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you that worked
weirdly enough, I tried JSON.parse() before and it didn't give me anything ...

Comment: so I tried this in a test environment and it worked.
but when I implement it, I get the following console log    SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF does anyone know what that is all about ?

@Nikhil your answer was correct but now it doesn't seem to be working cause this parsing error somewhere along the line ....

Comment: send me the output of console.log(data);

Comment: It's because the return data is not properly formatted or some unwanted data in the response.

Comment: yes thats what I thought, but I can't seem to find where theres something going wrong.

[Error] SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF
 parse (user-accounts.php, line 255)
 success (user-accounts.php, line 255)
 j (jquery-2.1.3.min.js, line 2)
 fireWith (jquery-2.1.3.min.js, line 2)
 x (jquery-2.1.3.min.js, line 4)
 (anonymous function) (jquery-2.1.3.min.js, line 4)

thats what the console s giving out

Comment: Are you getting this error when doing  console.log(data); ? There is no error in the client side script. Double check the changes you've made in the remote file. Double check the response data.

Comment: yes when I do console.log(data); I get said error
I have edited the server side script to only echo and json_encode the string accordingly but still the error persists
echo json_encode(array('msg'=>'the message')); this is the only line of code now in sc_update_user_role.php

Comment: Can you remove the external file inclusions from the serverside script and try? Because, when I tried your code the output is correct.

Comment: yes I did remove the external file includes but still no positiv result. The funny thing is, that I tried the exact same code in test environment meaning only on button to execute the ajax call and it worked. But in context it doesn't work. I can't figure out what is wrong with the code though.

Comment: So I got a little more out of the firefox log: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.

Comment: Open the server script in the browser and check the result. The server throw an error and if we do not know that error we can't say you something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use async

```
function getData(){
  var output;
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "sc_update_user.php",
   data: { 
     role_Id: 'my Id', 
     user_Id: 'user Id'    
   },
  async: false,
  success: function(data){
    output = data;
  }
});
return outuput;
}

alert("Data: "+getData());
```